# Regular expression applied on SQL script

Tags: regex

I am trying to parse SQL script coming from merging many files. I am interested just catching and throw an exception whenever the script contains the following

```
USE Database GO
```

or

```
use database
go
```

or

```
Use DATABASE

Go
```

and all the similar exceptions, at any point of the text. 
What regex may I use?

Comment: What language are you using the regular expression to parse with?

Comment: it is not clear in which context are you doing this.

Comment: @AlexW, I need to parse some text with a regular expression, in the language that you prefer... let's say Javascript or Java or C#

Comment: added some more examples

Comment: @1010 sorry, I don't know how to give more context... parsing text with a Regex to find some occurrences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below regex to match both type of string formats.

```
(?i)\bUSE +Database\s+GO
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xH3iL5/2)

A probably more complete scenario could be covered by

```
(?i)\bUSE +Database\s*[;]?\s+GO
```

In case the text to parse contains `;` e.g.:

```
USE database;
GO
```

Comment: He will probably need `(?i)USE\s+Database\s+GO`

Comment: @AlexW your regex will also match `USE\ndatabase\nGo`

Comment: Almost there, @AvinashRaj - but your regex also match the "misuse database go", I would possibly to limit the case on the specific word "use"

Comment: add a word boundary `(?i)\bUSE +Database\s+GO` or lookbehind `(?i)(?<=\s|^)USE +Database\s+GO`

Comment: amazing, `(?i)\bUSE +Database\s+GO` works perfectly :) thank you!